# In stellar astrophysics, what is the difference between protostellar disk and circumstellar disk?

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, stars, stellar-physics

I have noticed both the terms "protostellar disk" and "circumstellar disk" in the stellar astrophysics and exoplanet literature.

What exactly is the difference?

Comment: I think the difference between them is whether or not a star has formed, but I'm not certain of that distinction.

Comment: A circumstellar disk is a disk around a star. A protostellar disk is a disk surrounding a protostar. Nothing more complicated than that really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proto-stellar disk is composed of gas and dust from a giant molecular dust cloud that collapses into itself because of gravitational attraction.  It's an early stage in the formation of a star.  The collapse may be triggered by shock waves passing through the molecular cloud which disrupt the balance between inward gravitation and outward gas pressure that otherwise would maintain the cloud.  A proto-star forms from the proto-stellar disk.  Here is a short treatise on the detection of proto-stellar disks: http://www.cv.nrao.edu/vla/upgrade/node44.html.

After a proto-star has formed from a proto-stellar disk, a torus or pancake-shaped disk of debris may remain circling the star as it further collapses into itself and fusion begins.  Additional interstellar debris may fall into the gravitational field of the star and may join the remnants of the proto-stellar disk to form a circum-stellar cloud which condenses to a disk.  These disks are believed to be the birthplaces of planets.

There is more than one way of accounting for star formation, however.  Here is an abstract of a paper that explains how a circum-stellar disk follows after a proto-stellar disk: http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0920.  Be careful of terminology, as the abstract doesn't name the proto-stellar stage.

Answer (score 0):

A circumstellar disk is a set of objects that orbit about a star-like object and that collectively look disk-like in some way. A protostellar disk is thus a kind of circumstellar disk, the asteroid belt and the Kuiper belt about our Sun are also circumstellar disks.